# Found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, Error

Tags: ios, swift, null, xcode6, optional-values

I don't know where that optional is. please help! I really need this, I haven't used optional values in my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //this is the outlet for the sliders RGB values
    @IBOutlet weak var redSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var greenSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var blueSlider: UISlider!

    //this are the outlets for the labels
    @IBOutlet weak var redLabelValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var greenLabelValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var blueLabelValue: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var hexColor: UILabel!

    func changeThumbImage() {
        let redThumbImage = UIImage(named: "RedThumb@3x")
        redSlider.setThumbImage(redThumbImage, forState: .Normal)

        let greenThumbImage = UIImage(named: "GreenThumb@3x")
        greenSlider.setThumbImage(greenThumbImage, forState: .Normal)

        let blueThumbImage = UIImage(named: "BlueThumb@3x")
        blueSlider.setThumbImage(blueThumbImage, forState: .Normal)
    }

    func colorValues() {
        var roundedRed = UInt32(redSlider.value)
        var roundedGreen = UInt32(greenSlider.value)
        var roundedBlue = Int32(blueSlider.value)

        //converts the slider value to a string
        redLabelValue.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: roundedRed)
        greenLabelValue.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: roundedGreen)
        blueLabelValue.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: roundedBlue)
    }

    func rgbValues() {
        var redValue = Int(redSlider.value)
        var greenValue = Int(greenSlider.value)
        var blueValue = Int(blueSlider.value)
    }

    //VIEW DID LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateBackgroundColor()
        colorValues()
        changeThumbImage()

        redSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 100,y: 100,width: 200,height: 25))

    func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{

        let uniformRed = UInt32(redSlider.value)
        let uniformGreen = UInt32(greenSlider.value)
        let uniformBlue = UInt32(blueSlider.value)

        var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(uniformRed))
        var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(uniformGreen))
        var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(uniformBlue))

        return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    //view.backgroundColor = getRandomColor()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func updateBackgroundColor() {
        colorValues()
        //constant to set the value of the slider to a CGFloat
        let redValue = CGFloat(redSlider.value/255)
        let greenValue = CGFloat(greenSlider.value/255)
        let blueValue = CGFloat(blueSlider.value/255)
        //set the RGBA values
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1)

        //get the hexadecimal value from the RGB color values
        let hexValue = String(format:"%02X", Int(redSlider.value)) + String(format:"%02X", Int(greenSlider.value)) + String(format:"%02X", Int(blueSlider.value))

        hexColor.text = "#\(hexValue)"
    }

    //get rid of status bar
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: what is up with the redSlider? why do you set it explicitly?

Comment: what do you mean explicitly? @luk2302 with the bang operator?

Comment: why `redSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 100,y: 100,width: 200,height: 25))`? Is the redSlider not connected via IB?

Comment: To add an image to the thumb of the uislider

Comment: It is connected through IB

Comment: but there are not such lines for green and blue. Is the redSlider connected in the interface builder? Btw: provide the line where the crash occurs, maybe by adding an "Exception Breakpoint"

Comment: line 37:  var roundedRed = UInt32(redSlider.value)

Comment: I deleted the redSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 100,y: 100,width: 200,height: 25)) and now it works! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, first off, all of your outlets could potentially be nil at some point, so a good start would be adding ? to optionally unwrap them all.  If you do this, it will just do nothing instead of crash in the case that the Optional is nil.  Below I went through and added this to some of your code, but you may need to add a few more ? to other optionals I overlooked. Another way to do this is to use if-let unwrapping, which will reduce the amount of "?", but increase the amount of nesting.

```
func changeThumbImage() {
    let redThumbImage = UIImage(named: "RedThumb@3x")
    redSlider?.setThumbImage(redThumbImage, forState: .Normal)

    let greenThumbImage = UIImage(named: "GreenThumb@3x")
    greenSlider?.setThumbImage(greenThumbImage, forState: .Normal)

    let blueThumbImage = UIImage(named: "BlueThumb@3x")
    blueSlider?.setThumbImage(blueThumbImage, forState: .Normal)
}

//// 
func colorValues() {
    var roundedRed = UInt32(redSlider.value)
    var roundedGreen = UInt32(greenSlider.value)
    var roundedBlue = Int32(blueSlider.value)

    //converts the slider value to a string
    redLabelValue?.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: roundedRed)
    greenLabelValue?.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: roundedGreen)
    blueLabelValue?.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: roundedBlue)
}
```

Also use if-let here to safely unwrap the sliders...

```
@IBAction func updateBackgroundColor() {
    colorValues()

    if let red = redSlider, green = greenSlider, blue = blueSlider{
        let redValue = CGFloat(red.value/255)
        let greenValue = CGFloat(green.value/255)
        let blueValue = CGFloat(blue.value/255)

        //set the RGBA values
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1)

        //get the hexadecimal value from the RGB color values
        let hexValue = String(format:"%02X", Int(redSlider.value)) + String(format:"%02X", Int(greenSlider.value)) + String(format:"%02X", Int(blueSlider.value))

        hexColor?.text = "#\(hexValue)"
    }
}
```

Comment: For the last method, changed it to use if-let to unwrap the sliders.

Comment: also note, if you happened to forgot to connect one of the items in IB to an outlet or somehow accidentally unlinked it from the outlet, it will have a nil value.

Comment: I downvoted because adding a `?` will just cause the program to potentially not work properly without any indication what went wrong. For example he would not receive an error message which he can post and request help with. If everything works as intended, they will never be nil. You should not wrap your entire program in a single try-catch just to remove the crashes. Because if you encounter a point where your code does not work anymore and you have no idea why the next statements are similarly unpredictable. You should make sure the program is written correctly in the first place.

Comment: Similarly for the if-let, at least provide an else-block where you do some error handling.

Comment: im sure he doesn't need an error message if his label fails to set the color..., but sure....

Comment: It is not primarily regarding the color - more generally, just suppressing actual errors instead of investigating and fixing them is not a good idea.

Comment: well thanks I do appreciate the feedback, but I still think that an error case for setting each outlet here is not worth the effort and neither is nesting a single line in an if-let.  Additionally, the only likely case that will cause these to be nil will be when the outlet is not connected properly or when subclassing the VC without having the same views connected.

Comment: although, if you want to edit my answer to add error handling,.. I won't be offended.